# Excel Report Generation from Access Database

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to generate an excel report where the data is coming from access database using VB.

Answer (score 2):

1.http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6606

> The purpose of this programme is to
>   generate report by populating data
>   into an Ms-Excel sheet from an
>   Ms-Access database.

2.http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Senthil_S__Software_Eng_.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel 2007 or 2010 file format is acceptable, you can utilize MS Open XML SDK 2.0.  Just use your favorite search engine to find the download the SDK.  Some examples can be found at www.openxmldeveloper.org.  The other option that you have is to just setup a data source using an ODC (office data connection) file and bind to it in Excel.